# lookahead with backreference

Tags: regex, perl, sed, awk

hope you can help here

I wish to match strings where in the following regex, \2 doesn't match \4.

```
^(\w{2,5}[FGHJKMNQUVXZ])(\d)-(\w{2,5}[FGHJKMNQUVXZ])(\d)$
```

I have tried a char class:

```
^(\w{2,5}[FGHJKMNQUVXZ])(\d)-(\w{2,5}[FGHJKMNQUVXZ])[^\2]$
```

But my regex library (C++ boost) is complaining that \2 is an invalid octal.

I suppose that a lookaround is the answer, however,

```
^(\w{2,5}[FGHJKMNQUVXZ])(\d)-(\w{2,5}[FGHJKMNQUVXZ])(?!\2)$
```

Is not working either.

Any clues?

Many thanks

TC

Comment: Do you have some example input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(?!\2)` is a zero-width assertion and does not consume characters.  Since it is followed by `$`, that means the regex will not match if there actually is a digit in that spot even if it does not match `\2`.   Give this a try:

```
^(\w{2,5}[FGHJKMNQUVXZ])(\d)-(\w{2,5}[FGHJKMNQUVXZ])(?!\2)(\d)$
```